# Relation between the derivative of hurwitz zeta and trigamma

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, special-functions, riemann-zeta, polygamma

How to prove that

$$\zeta '(-1, 1/3)- \zeta '(-1, 2/3) = \frac{\psi ' (1/3)}{6 \sqrt{3} \pi}-\frac{\pi}{9 \sqrt{3}}$$

Does there exist a general formula for

$$\zeta '(-1, x)- \zeta '(-1, 1-x) $$